# Why is Microsoft.Z3 assembly not signed?

Tags: z3

I would like to put the Z3 (V3.2) assembly into the GAC, but it is not signed.
Is there a reason for that ?

Answer (score 1):

The 64 bit managed DLL is built with a self-signed key, the 32-bit DLL is not. This looks like a bug and I will check if we can add a workable delay signing to the 32-bit version as well. We don't build already signed assemblies, but components that use Z3 have so far been able to integrate delay signed assemplies that we provide per requests.